Implementation of sinleton class, private constructor, still initiallizing, do I need to access Singleton from another class to make it work?
how am I able to create an instance of Singleton s3 even when the constructor is private, tried in local env and online compiler as well, it is running
public class Singleton {
    
    // Step 1: Declare a private static instance of the Singleton class
    private static Singleton s = null;

    // Step 2: Make the constructor private to prevent instantiation
    private Singleton() {
    }

    // Step 3: Provide a public static method to get the instance
    public static Singleton getIns() {
        if (s == null) { // Check if an instance already exists
            s = new Singleton(); // Create a new instance if it doesn't
        }
        return s; // Return the Singleton instance
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Singleton s1 = Singleton.getIns();
        Singleton s2 = Singleton.getIns();

        
         Singleton s3 = new Singleton(); 

        
        System.out.println(s1 == s2); // Output should be true
    }
}

I was expecting a compilation error for s3, but it is compiling and running fine

By the way, your code is not thread-safe. A gap of time exists between your null check and your instantiation (non-atomic).

@001 No, not a duplicate of that. That other Question asks about access to private member fields from main. This Question asks about instantiation despite the constructor being private.

But since the instantiation happens in main I think it’s close enough.

@001 I disagree. Accessing member fields is technically distinct from instantiation. Entirely different sections of the Java Language Specification.

Java Language Specification 6.6.1. Determining Accessibility does not make any distinction between members (class, interface, field, or method) and constructor: "... Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private. Access is permitted only when one of the following is true: Access occurs from within the body of the top level class or interface that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor. ..."

@user85421 I stand corrected. Thank you.

By the way, the best route to implement a Singleton in Java is enum. Example: public enum MyExampleSingleton { INSTANCE ; } Add state and constructor.
